# tkinter bug in filename window

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am developing a Python/Tk application on a Raspberry Pi (ver.4 Model B Rev 1.2).

Its OS is 5.4.83-1-MANJARO-ARM #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 14 08:37:33 CST 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux

The software versions are python 3.9.1 and tkinter version tk 8.6.12-1

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but any *tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename* call shows this:

[image: snapshot showing the bug...]

with the filenames invisible, unless you select them one after the other: in that case the selected filenames remain visible...

Let me know if there is a solution, please...

Comment: Tkinter just calls the operating system for filedialog.

Comment: Thank you! So you think it's a Manjaro issue?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this matter, I try to reach out to the maintainer of this section. All I can tell that it seems to work for others https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=53607